# VBA Copy two ranges and combine them, then save in text file

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy two ranges of cells from two separate worksheets in one file, and combine them then save then into a text file. I only know how to save one range of cells into txt. file like the code below.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Count As Range

LastRow = Range("K" & Sheets("Reports").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  Dim wbText As Workbook
  Dim wsReports As Worksheet

  Set wbText = Workbooks.Add

  Set wsReports = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports")

  With wsReports
    .Range("Q2" & ":Q" & LastRow).Copy wbText.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
  End With

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  With wbText
   .SaveAs Filename:="P:\Newsletter Email.txt", FileFormat:=xlText
   .Close False
  End With
```

This code copies  column F in sheet Reports in to the text file, but I also need to copy column L from sheet Reports1 into the text file. I know

```
RangeCombined = Union(Range1, Range2)
```

Could combine two ranges, how can I integrate this code into this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRow1 As Long
Dim Count As Range

Dim wbText As Workbook
Dim wsReports As Worksheet
Dim wsReports1 As Worksheet

Set wbText = Workbooks.Add

Set wsReports = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports")
Set wsReports1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports1")

LastRow = wsReports.Range("K" & wsReports.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow1 = wsReports1.Range("K" & wsReports1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

wsReports.Range("Q2" & ":Q" & LastRow).Copy wbText.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
wsReports1.Range("F2" & ":F" & LastRow1).Copy wbText.Sheets(1).Range("B1")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With wbText
   .SaveAs Filename:="P:\Newsletter Email.txt", FileFormat:=xlText
   .Close False
End With
```

This will copy column Q of Reports into column A of the output, and column F of Reports1 into column B of the output.

Alternatively, if you want column F of Reports1 to appear below column Q of Reports, change the Copy statements to be:

```
wsReports.Range("Q2" & ":Q" & LastRow).Copy wbText.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
wsReports1.Range("F2" & ":F" & LastRow1).Copy wbText.Sheets(1).Range("A" & LastRow)
```

(If there are the same number of rows in both Reports and Reports1, the above can be simplified a bit.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to save the file to a path while printing to it. Try this

```
Dim FilePath As String
Dim lCol As String
Dim fCol As String
Dim fRange As String
Dim lRange As String
Dim wsReports As Worksheet
Dim wsReports1 As Worksheet

Set wsReports = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports")
Set wsReports1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports1")

FilePath = "P:\Newsletter Email.txt"

fRange = "F2:F" & LastRow
lRange = "L2:L" & LastRow
'Will create the file if it does not exist
Open FilePath For Output As #1
With wsReports
.Range("Q2" & ":Q" & lastrow).Copy wbText.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
For i = 0 To lastrow
fCol = .Cells(i, "F")

Print #1, fCol
Next i

End With
With wsReports1
For i = 0 To lastrow
lCol = .Cells(i, "L")
Print #1, lCol
Next i
End With
'Make sure to close it or you'll have difficulties opening the file
Close #1
```

Comment: But these two ranges are from two work sheets, "Reports" and "Reports1". I see you set the wsReport as worksheet("Reports"), and never mention "Reports1".

Comment: I just edited to include wsReports1. It should still print to the same file even if its from another worksheet

Comment: Why you have to dim a range as string, I didn't see you using it after you dim it.

Comment: That was an accident. Meant to use fRange and lRange instead of only range. Updated the code to reflect it

Comment: Now it is saying there is a mismatch in the sentence `fCol = .Range(fRange)`. And it seems to create a new worksheets in the original file, since I dim wbText as workbook, and set wbText = workbooks.Add.

Comment: Switched it on over to .Cells and passed the values individually to the file. Try it out. If you don't want to add a sheet, take out the Set wbText = Workbooks.Add

Comment: I appreciate your hard work, it almost did it. It is still saying `fCol = .Cells(i, "K")`is a mismatch

Comment: After looking at your code again, I think it may have something to do with the way that LastRow is initialized. Maybe it should be LastRow = ws.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row ? If not, post updated code and maybe screenshot of sheet you're working with

Comment: Could you update the code to the correct solution please? I would like to see as it had me stumped for a little lol. Glad I could help

Comment: I used the one I picked as the answer.